# C language if statement: writing a loop for a more elegant solution?

Tags: loops

i was wondering if anybody might be able to come up with a solution that would negate the use of multiple if statements. so that my request is clear, two sets of code have been provided. the first set of code is the working code, the second set of code is an attempt at writing a loop that would fulfil the purpose of an elegant solution (i.e- by expressing the pattern used in the working answer as a general algorithm).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    

int main()    
{
    char str[10] = "copy000000";
    int i = 9;
    int a,b,c;


    for (a = 0; a < 10; a++)  
    {        

    str[i]++;

    for (b = 0; b < 6; b++)
    {    
    if (str[5] == ':')
        {
        str[5] = '0';
        str[4]++;
        }

    if (str[6] == ':')
        {
        str[6] = '0';
        str[5]++;
        }

    if (str[7] == ':')
        {
        str[7] = '0';
        str[6]++;
        }

    if (str[8] == ':')
        {
        str[8] = '0';
        str[7]++;
        }

    if (str[9] == ':')
        {
        str[9] = '0';
        str[8]++;
        }
     }

    printf("string is: %s\n", str);    
    b = 0;           
    }     

return 0;
}
```

This code produces output of the form:

```
string is: copy000001
string is: copy000002
string is: copy000003
string is: copy000004
string is: copy000005
string is: copy000006
string is: copy000007
string is: copy000008
string is: copy000009
string is: copy000010
string is: copy000011
string is: copy000012
string is: copy000013
```

attempted solution to generalize how the if loops have been iterated:

```
    for (c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
    if (str[d] == ':')
        {
        str[d] = '0';
        str[d-1]++;
        d++;
        }
    }
```

produces output of the form:

```
string is: copy000001
string is: copy000002
string is: copy000003
string is: copy000004
string is: copy000005
string is: copy000006
string is: copy000007
string is: copy000008
string is: copy000009
string is: copy00000:
string is: copy00000;
string is: copy00000<
string is: copy00000=
```

any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `str[d] = '\0';` instead? Your current attempt fails to 9-terminate the strings…

Answer (score 0):

Just make the inner for cycle with b variable like this and it should work:

```
for(b=9; b > 4; b--){
    if(str[b]==':'){
        str[b] = '0';
        str[b-1]++;
    }
}
```

You simply increment the numbers from last digit moving to first.

If you only need this for printing, consider keeping the number in integer or long and printing it using printf %d option as described in [C/C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

EDIT: missed a semicolon